# Isospin and indistinguishable particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles, isospin-symmetry

I am trying to understand the properties of a proton-neutron system assuming that isospin is a good symmetry, so I will forget about electromagnetism, weak interactions, QCD and all those more sophisticated ideas. Let's consider then that the *nucleon* is a fundamental particle with isospin $T=1/2$, so that $T_3=1/2$ corresponds to a proton and $T_3=-1/2$ corresponds to a neutron. My question is, in this situation, can the proton and the neutron be considered as indistinguishable fermions, and therefore any state of two of these nucleons must be antisymmetric with respect to the interchange of the dynamical variables corresponding to each nucleon? In general, that would mean that a state where $N$ and $N'$ represent any two nucleons (i.e., any values for the third component of isospin)  satisfies:

$$ \Phi_{\xi,N;\,\xi',N'} = - \Phi_{\xi',N';\,\xi,N} $$

where by $\Phi_{\xi,N;\,\xi',N'}$ I mean a state in the Hilbert space of the theory containing a nucleon of type $N$ with other variables $\xi$ (momentum, third component of spin, ...) and another nucleon of type $N'$ with other variables $\xi'$. I know that this must be true if $N=N'$, e.g., for two protons we must have:

$$ \Phi_{\xi,p;\,\xi',p} = - \Phi_{\xi',p;\,\xi,p} $$

but the really interesting case for me is the one where we have a proton and a neutron:

$$ \Phi_{\xi,p;\,\xi',n} = - \Phi_{\xi',n;\,\xi,p} $$

If this were true, that would mean that the proton and the neutron are in fact indistinguishable, assuming of course that isospin is a good symmetry (which I know it isn't, but the point here is to understand how far the idea of indistinguhishability can be taken in a theory with internal symmetries such as isospin).

Comment: What if we discuss all these in the frame of quark model. The concept of isospin or isotopic spin was first proposed by Werner Heisenberg in 1932 to explain the similarities between protons and neutrons under the strong
interaction. Murray Gell-Mann proposed the quark model in 1964. The success of the isospin model is now understood to be the result of the similar masses of the $\:\mathbf{u}\:$  and $\:\mathbf{d}\:$ quarks.

Comment: @Frobenius I know, but I think isospin is an easy toy model to understand my last question, which in fact is the most important one (although the practical problem that suggested it was the proton-neutron system)... In a theory with internal symmetries, how do we take them into account when talking about indistinguishable particles? I suppose you could go to the quark model to understand the proton-neutron system, but that is not the main point of my question... Thank you for your comment anyway!

Comment: (+1) OK. I wish to have good answers

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking, but the generalized Pauli principle (read up an introductory particle physics texts such as Perkins) dictates antisymmetry of 2 fermion wavefunctions with respect to all quantum numbers, superposed on each other: try spin first, isospin, color symmetry for quarks, etc...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122110/44126, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153422/44126