# Allowed Isospin states of two nucleons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, isospin-symmetry

I have a question on my Quantum Mechanics homework where we consider protons and neutrons to be manifestations of the same particle -- a **nucleon**. We think of the proton as the "isospin up state", and the neutron as the "isospin down state" are asked to consider a two-particle state as a tensor product of orbital angular momentum $| l m_l \rangle$, spin angular momentum $|S m_S \rangle$, and isospin $|I m_I \rangle$ i.e.

$$|N N ; lm_l, Sm_S, Im_I \rangle =  | l m_l \rangle \otimes | S m_S \rangle \otimes | I m_I \rangle $$

We are then asked two questions:

**(1). What are the allowed isospin states for two nucleons in terms of the proton/neutron basis?**

**(2). At low energies, most two-nucleon observables are dominated by the $l = 0$ angular momentum. If we fix $l = 0$, what are the allowed spin and isospin two-nucleon states?**

This may be a stupid question, but how does $| l m_l \rangle \otimes | S m_S \rangle \otimes | I m_I \rangle$ describe a two-particle space?  Isn't this describing a *single* nucleon which is a proton if $m_I = \frac{1}{2}$ and a neutron if $m_I = -\frac{1}{2}$? Meaning a *two*-particle state would look something like

$$(| l m_l \rangle \otimes | S m_S \rangle \otimes | I m_I \rangle)_1 \otimes (| l' m_l' \rangle \otimes | S' m_S' \rangle \otimes | I' m_I' \rangle)_2 $$

I've included my currently line of attack for the question, but am unsure and would greatly appreciate any guidance.

My approach to (1):

The allowed isospin states have the basis $|p \rangle \otimes | p\rangle$,  $|p \rangle \otimes |n \rangle$,  $|n \rangle \otimes | p \rangle$, and  $|n \rangle \otimes |n \rangle$. Since we are adding two spin-1/2 particles, I think we need to use the fact that their total angular momentum $(j)$ ranges between $s_1 + s_2 = 1$ and $|s_1 - s_2| = 0$ to form the various states with different combinations of $l$ and $s$ values.

My approach to (2):

Using the states found in (1), we just restrict to those with $l = 0$ and take tensor products between the

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/122150/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/155827/44126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, $$ |N_1 \rangle = | l_1 m_{l_1} \rangle \otimes | S_1 m_{S_1} \rangle \otimes | I_1 m_{I_1} \rangle$$ describes state of first nucleon and $$ |N_2 \rangle = | l_2 m_{l_2} \rangle \otimes | S_2 m_{S_2} \rangle \otimes | I_2 m_{I_2} \rangle$$ describes state of second nucleon.

Then the two nucleon state can be written as $$ |N_1N_2 \rangle = | l m_{l} \rangle \otimes | S m_{S} \rangle \otimes | I m_{I} \rangle, $$where $\vec{l} =  \vec{l}_1 + \vec{l}_2 $, $\vec{S} =  \vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2 $ and $\vec{I} =  \vec{I}_1  
+ \vec{I}_2$. Means it’s a coupled state. If you are not familiar with it, read how angular momentum coupling is done and about CG coefficients. For the 1st question $l$ is arbitrary, so don't worry about its coupling. Couple the spin and isospin states. Write the coupled states in terms of uncoupled states by calculating the CG coefficients.

Depending upon the values of $l$, $ S $ and $I$ you can now determine the symmetry of the states. And then due of **Pauli exclusion principle**, you have to identify the states which make the total two particle state antisymmetric when we exchange the particles.

For $ l = 0 $ state the space part is always is symmetric. So the product of spin and isospin part has to be antisymmetric.

This will be bit complicated for a beginner, better to follow a nuclear physics book where the **deuteron problem (two nucleon problem)** is mentioned in detail. Check how deuteron states are formed.

Book recommendation: Nuclear physics by Roy and Nigam

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!